# If i will remove a tabPage,auto selects first tabPage in my tabControl

Tags: c#

I have a tabControl with 4 tabPages tabPage1,tabPage2,tabPage3,tabPage4
I'm usnig this code in tabPage4 for closing it with a button click

```
 tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveByKey("tabPage4");
```

the problem is that when my tabPage will close it auto selects my tabPage1.
My desired result is i want to select last opened tabPage.In my case i need to selects tabPage3.
How can i fix that? Is there any option in tabControl properties panel?

Comment: Save the last opened tab when u switch tabs

Comment: What do you mean?TabPage Name?

Comment: The index. If it is higher than the deleted one, you need to subtract 1. Otherwise don't subtract anything

Comment: use tabcontrol.SelectedIndex = 2 after you remove tabPage4

Comment: I also add tabpages dynamically so selected index =2 doesnt help a lot.@ Psi can you give me an example?

Comment: Simply select the desired tab page first and *then* remove the page.  Beware that this code is almost certainly wrong, the tabpage and its controls are not actually destroyed and will leak forever.  You **must** use Dispose() instead.

Comment: Ok thans for the ansewrs.I just wonder if there is simplier way through tabcontrol properties or something like that